# Firebase throwing insufficient permissions error on filtered query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to query a subset of a collection from firestore. My firestore rules for the route are

```
match /data/{firstId}/subCol/{secondId}/subSubCol/{thirdId} {
    allow create: if true;
    allow read: if resource.data.authorUid == request.auth.uid;
    allow write: if resource.data.authorUid == request.auth.uid;
    allow delete: if resource.data.authorUid == request.auth.uid;
}
```

I can write to the document at this location perfectly fine. However, whenever I attempt to a frontend query like this:

```
const getAllDocsFromCollection(firstId, secondId) {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const userId = auth?.currentUser?.uid
    if(!userId) {
        throw new Error("UserId undefined")
    }

    const colQuery = query(collection(db, "data", firstId, "subCol", secondId, "subSubCol"), where("authorUid", "==", userId));
    const docs = await getDocs(colQuery);
    return docs;
}
```

I receive the error: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

All of the identifying information is correct, and when I attempt to write to an individual document from the frontend it works fine. There is only an issue when I pull the collection. I know that when attempting to get all docs from a firestore collection, if a rule fails on any single doc, the entire query fails, however, in this instance, I believe am using a frontend query that should filter the collection and only pull docs the user has access to.

Comment: Can you show how `userId` is initialized when you call `getAllDocsFromCollection`?

Comment: user id is a string that comes from the auth token. I've logged it and it is the correct value (equal to the authorUid in the database)

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment, but edit your question show the code for how `userId` is initialized and pass to the call to `getAllDocsFromCollection`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Apologies, updated the post

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Apologies, Updated the post, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hmm... at first glance that all looks good. Maybe somebody else spots what wrong, but otherwise: do you think you can set up a minimal repro on a site like stackblitz.com so that we can all poke at it (I have a separate database for such repros, and recommend doing the same).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is a good idea. I will do that, and update the post. Thanks for your replies.